# 2D arrays are wack in python, can someone help me with this issue i'm having?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a game where it uses a 2D array, in python, as the map, and from where the player is, only renders what's around them. I'm doing this on `VScode` and the issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how to start with the program that detects what's around the player. As well as having different int values as different parts of the environment. It will take the number then show a texture that's stored in a list. This will all show in the terminal because I hate myself.

My first solution was to turn the `gamemap` into a List then go a number of spots into the list to get the value next them so on and so forth but the issue i ran into is that it only works if the map is a square or rectangle. This is really bothering me as I need it for a project.

Comment: Could you add your attempt to solve the problem into the question? As the question is currently written, it is too vague to answer.

Comment: the 2nd paragraph was my attempt to solve it. By trying to convert it into a single list. lets say i have a 7 by 7 2D array then the player is in [2][3]. im trying to find a way to find out what's around the player. Like for example in [3][3] or [1][4]. I'm just very lost so if you could help i would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you also give the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The 2d array could be interpreted as a plane containing your real map.

1. displays have typically a rectangular shape.
2. pin the player to the center of your display.
3. calculate the convex hull of the polygons which make up your real map.
4. calculate the bounding box for your real map and use it to construct the 2d array.
5. you could also add a number of tiles corresponding to half of the display width to the left und right and a number of tiles corresponding to half the hight of your Display to the top and bottom. This makes clipping unneccessary for your renderer.
6. initialize your map with somthing you call *nothing*. Then oberride the cells which are use with your maps values.
7. Make sure the player can not step on *nothing*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map like

```
map = [[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
       [' ',' ',' ','P',' ',' '],
       [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']]
```

and adjust to however long and many you want it to be. For the only register around the player, you could do something like:

```
for a in range(3):
    for b in range(3):
        print(map[b-1][x-2+a] + '\n')
```

or just do print(map[0][x-2+a]) and print(map[1][x-2+a]) and so on. Your choice.

Comment: Don't name the variable `map`; that will cause you to lose access to the built-in map function.

Comment: That was just a placeholder you can use like m or something.